# Android -- Live wallpaper OPENGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I'm created an OPENGL activity that it's a 3D Cube and moves and does different things. How can I use this OPENGL activity to use it like an android wallpaper?
Could you pass me links or different stuff?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links:

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers

http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/376/android-ui-making-a-live-wallpaper-fire-simulation/

Comment: The code from rbgrn.net that you linked to above is currently maintained here: https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService